# Network speed problem on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: wifi, internet, performance

Both my desktop (running Windows Subsystem for Linux) and raspberry pi 3 connect to router via WiFi.

Download speed from internet on desktop is decent :

```
~/tmp$ wget https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-10.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
   debian-10.2.0-amd64-D   7%[=>                                 ] 287.30M  `11.5MB/s`    eta 4m 51s
```

Download (with no other major network activities going on, of course) speed from internet on rasp pi is more than 10 times slower :

```
pi:/data/tmp$ wget https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-10.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
debian-10.2.0-amd64-DVD-   2%[                                   ]  95.29M   `846KB/s`    eta 78m 3s
```

scp between the two is even slower :

```
~/tmp$ scp rasp:tmp/debian-10.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso ./
debian-10.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso                                    46%   16MB `218.5KB/s`   01:29 ETA
```

What could have caused problem of speed on rasp pi?
How can I go about troubeshooting the problem ?

Comment: Possibly TCP packet loss, because the desktop has a better antennae and/or location. https://serverfault.com/questions/318909/how-passively-monitor-for-tcp-packet-loss-linux

Comment: Fire up this command: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`. Any improvement?

Comment: @goldilocks thanks I'll take a look.

Comment: @M. Rostami, thanks, no improvement.